# PHP array to object good or bad practice

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I'm creating a tree like data structure for a customized web application using arrays but i found it hard to access nested arrays inside the root of the tree

```
//this is the code i have created
$Root = array(
    'car' => array(
         'id' => '0009'
         'driver' => 'david',
         'color' => 'red'
     ) 
    'bus' => array(
         'id' => '0010'
         'driver' => 'alex',
         'color' => 'green'
     )
);
```

so wheen returning an item i must do that

```
$driver = $root['car']['driver'];
```

Converting all these arrays to objects by adding '(object)' before 'array()' will solve the problem like this :

```
$Root = (object)array(
    'car' => (object)array(
         'id' => '0009'
         'driver' => 'david',
         'color' => 'red'
     ) 
    'bus' => (object)array(
         'id' => '0010'
         'driver' => 'alex',
         'color' => 'green'
     )
);
```

so now to i may access the items by:

```
$driver = $root->car->driver;
```

The question now, is this way has performance problems when creating multiple arrays with 100 items or more for each ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad practice. Why do you convert your arrays into object? Use them as an array. If you want objects, then create a class file, and use objects, not just converting an array into object.

Comment: I agree, also you'd get benefits like inheritance.  Vehicle > Car, Vehicle > Bus, etc..

Comment: well, the problem is the content of arrays is dynamic and keys of the arrays are driven from database or 'GET' parameters. so i cannot create classes and add properties with static names to them.

if you have another way, please write a code sample :) :) .

Comment: look up __set(), __get() -- dynamic properties in php.  That is really not much better though, you should know ahead of time what the properties are.  Otherwise how can you validate or work with anything.

Comment: ok, magic __get and __set are very good solution for my design

Comment: what if you have data from some store and it comes as an array. still being a bad idea make a change to object ?

Comment: @jrodriguez If you have a pre-built class, then you can make object of that through constructor or setters, if you use that newly created object for some purposes. Just to look like some high tech programmer who  uses object, then no, do not do that. the OOP has another goals.